# Bizarre HTML error (stopping include of CSS and JS files)

Tags: html, css, include, firebug

Here's the link to my problem:
http://alexcoady.co.uk/crumbl/

Basically, I'm getting nothing; just the markup, which I'm sure is bang on. The CSS file and jQuery file aren't getting pulled in though.. I'm a fairly experienced programmer and this is really throwing me, I'm sure I must be missing something.

Firebug says there's a Syntax error with the DOCTYPE line, there isn't.

**It's my .htaccess file - sorry, me being thick.**

Thank you!

Comment: It's my .htaccess file I think.. It needs to allow those files :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `.htaccess`. Aren't there any redirection rule?

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery-1.6.js file is actually an HTML page, and the error is referring to the doctype on that script.